# How to serialize a ViewState objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, gridview, viewstate

I have some functions that query a database and puts the result into a gridview. It also sets a ViewState variable that contains the results of the query. When I postback, I have a load function that loads the gridview from the last results if any.

The Problem I am having is that I am getting an error that basically says that the viewstate object needs to be serialized. From what I have I am not sure how to do this.

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error
>   serializing value
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType17`2[System.Int32,System.String]]'
>   of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[<>f__AnonymousType17`2[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   App_Web_rjb524gi, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]].'

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public partial class PlayersManagement : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

public void LoadData()
{

    if (ViewState["CurrentGridView"] != null || ViewState["CurrentGridView"] == "")
    {
        GridViewPlayers.DataSource = ViewState["CurrentGridView"];
        GridViewPlayers.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

        DBModel.DBEntities context = new  DBModel.DBEntities();

        var players= (from f in context.Players
                        where f.isDeleted == false
                        select new
                        {
                            f.PlayerId,
                            f.PlayerName

                        }).ToList();

        GridViewPlayers.DataSource = players;
        GridViewPlayers.DataBind();
    }

    ViewState["Sort"] = 0;

}


/**
   * This method is for advance search functionality 
   * 
   */
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // If the search textbox is not empty
    if (txtSearch.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        // Call to Entity Model Framework
       DBModel.DBEntities context = new DBModel.DBEntities();

        //Querying the Players table 
        var search = (from s in context.Players
                      where s.PlayerName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
                      select new
                      {
                          s.PlayerId,
                          s.PlayerName

                      }).ToList();


        if (search.Count != 0)
        {

            noResults.Visible = false;

            GridViewPlayers.DataSource = search;//Connecting query to the datasource Gridview

            ViewState["CurrentGridView"] = search; // <---- Error cause here

            GridViewPlayers.DataBind();  //Binding Gridview
        }
        else
        {
            noResults.Visible = true;
            noResults.Text = "This '" + txtSearch.Text + "' Query Returned No Results";

            txtSearch.Text = "";

        }


    }

}


 protected void Gridview_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

    //Label2.Text = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
     DBModel.DBEntities context = new  DBModel.DBEntities();

    var players = (from b in context.Players
                 where b.isDeleted == false
                 select b);

    DataTable gridviewTable = players.CopyToDataTable();

    gridviewTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

    GridViewPlayers.DataSource = gridviewTable;

    ViewState["CurrentGridView"] = gridviewTable; <--- Also causes error

    GridViewPlayers.DataBind();

}


private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    int sort = (ViewState["Sort"] == null) ? 0 : (int)ViewState["Sort"];
    switch (sort)
    {
        case 0:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            ViewState["Sort"] = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            ViewState["Sort"] = 0;
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}

protected void GridViewPlayers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewPlayers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    LoadData();
}


protected void GridViewPlayers_CancelEditRow(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewPlayers.EditIndex = -1;
    LoadData();
}
```

Comment: `GridViewPlayers.DataSource = ViewState["CurrentGridView"];` is unable to properly de-serialize the class. One choice is to add a `class Player{public int PlayerId;public string PlayerName;}` and cast the result e.g. `GridViewPlayers.DataSource = (List<Player>) ViewState["CurrentGridView"];`

Comment: Its seems that Session works, but I don't want the session object floating around the application, but rather kill it on a page change. Would this be better?

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to store it in View State then you will probably want to have a type that can be marked as `[Serializable]`.  It looks like the anonymous type is not.  So instead of using:

```
var search
```

use

```
 List<Player> search =  Query
```

And the class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId {get;set;}
    public string PlayerName {get;set;}
}
```

However, It looks like you are querying the db each time, so even if you did store in viewstate you wouldnt be gaining anything.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same kind of issue when storing a value inside ViewState (`Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException Error serializing value`) whereas  my class definition is marked as Serializable. I'm able to read and write the value from code behind, but I'm getting an error at client side.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you can't pass anonymous objects using the `ViewState`. One solution would be to create strongly typed models and use them instead the anonymous objects. Create a `Player` class:

```
public class Player
{
    public Int32 PlayerId { get; set; }
    public String PlayerName { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var search = (from s in context.Players
    where s.PlayerName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
    select new Player
    {
        PlayerId = s.PlayerId,
        PlayerName = s.PlayerName

    }).ToList();
```

instead of:

```
var search = (from s in context.Players
    where s.PlayerName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
    select new
    {
        s.PlayerId,
        s.PlayerName

    }).ToList();
```

Do this for all your *dynamic* results (change them to use concrete classes) and the binding resp. serialization resp. passing via `ViewState` should work properly.

Comment: So I thought the point of using EF (entity framework) was so that developers don't have to make model classes.

Comment: If your Entity already created Player class then try casting ViewState['something'] to Player[] and/or List<Player>

Comment: Yes, this is one of the tasks done from EF in order to help the developer, but you are not using the classes created by EF. Instead you are creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). If you already have a `Player` class created from EF, then use it instead of `select new {...`.